# java8 decode image which encoded in base64

Tags: java, base64, decode

I am trying to decode a image which encoded in base64 string with java.util.Base64 (java8). 

Here is the base64 encoded string:

```
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 29/j5+v/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8AvazJDPdraSXEcIijMoLuF+c8J19OT+VaWn3QvLGG4GPnXkDse4/OoNJ+cXUzcvJcOCfZTtA/IVny3ktje3cMG0J5u/BGcEqpP6mgD//Z
```

It can be decoded on http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

When I try to decode the base64 string to byte. I got this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 20
```

Here is my code:

```
String base64Str = "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 29/j5+v/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8AvazJDPdraSXEcIijMoLuF+c8J19OT+VaWn3QvLGG4GPnXkDse4/OoNJ+cXUzcvJcOCfZTtA/IVny3ktje3cMG0J5u/BGcEqpP6mgD//Z";
byte[] imageByteArray_new = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Str);
```

I have no idea of what is wrong. Please help, thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have a space in your encoded string, which is an illegal character in base64. If you remove it, it still generates the same image in the converter you linked to, and can be now decoded by your code as well.

**UPDATE:**

Some decoders (like the one you linked, or `Base64.getMimeDecoder()` in Java) ignore illegal characters, others (like `Base64.getDecoder()`) don't allow them.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem when I recieved the base64 String throught a @RequestParam, it recieved "+" as " ".

`Base64.getDecoder().decode()` gave me the same exception (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 20)
and `Base64.getMimeDecoder()` just ignored the spaces and saved the  image with errors.

fix:

`public byte[] convertImage(String base64) {
        String base64Image = base64.replaceAll(" ", "+");
        return byte[] imageBytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Image);
}`

And it worked for me.

Comment: thanks. I just did it straight without creating a new string

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, It works for me as well. Thanks a lot.**

```
 String base64Image = base64.replaceAll(" ", "+");
```

Query - I would say this is temporary solution because in encrypted string if would come blank or any other character then it won't work.